# send input data with onsubmit method

Tags: javascript

I have a **Multi** forms that contain some inputs

```
<form class="form" role="form" onsubmit="completeSave()">
 <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>نام محتوا</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
               value="{{$media->name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" id="{{$media->id}}" class="btn blue">ارایه</button>
    </div>
</form>
<form class="form" role="form" onsubmit="completeSave()">
 <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>نام محتوا</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
               value="{{$media->name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" id="{{$media->id}}" class="btn blue">ارایه</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to get value of inputs on submitting form I tried this code  but it didnt worked

```
function completeSave() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var thisForm = $(this);
        console.log(thisForm.find('input[name="name"]').val())
}
```

it returns undefined in console

Comment: why don't u use jQuery to make your job easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using jQuery for this case.
You need to import your jQuery then use below function
jQuery can be found at

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

function completeSave(e) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var thisForm = $(e).find("[name=name]");
   console.log(thisForm.val());
}
```

**FORM**

```
<form class="form" role="form" onsubmit="completeSave(this)"> <!-- add this -->
 <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>نام محتوا</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
               value="{{$media->name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" id="{{$media->id}}" class="btn blue">ارایه</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that there are more than one form in page so I cant just say `[name='name']` to find input value

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms

```
<form class="form" role="form" id="form1">
 <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>نام محتوا</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
               value="{{$media->name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="button" id="{{$media->id}}" class="btn blue" onclick="completeSave("form1");">ارایه</button>
    </div>
```

Scripts

```
function completeSave(formId) {
   console.log($("#"+formId+' input[name="name"]').val())
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I forgot to add that there are more than one form in page so I cant just say `[name='name']` to find input value

Comment: then you must put some ID on each form did you put some ID on it ? if you have you can easily acces it

Answer (score 0):

use this java script code

```
function completeSave() {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log($("#name").val());
}
```

but add an id on text input as -

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"
               value="{{$media->name}}">
```

Comment: I forgot to add that there are more than one form in page so I cant just say `[name='name']` to find input value

Answer (score 0):

fist i assume you are using **jquery**

> solution 1

the keyword `this` only evaluates to the `form` if the `completeSave` function 
is called via jquery's submit event, so for this solution, you don't need the `completeSave` function on the form's HTML tag

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var thisForm = $(event.target);
  console.log(thisForm.find('input[name="name"]').val())
})
```

> solution 2

you should pass the event argument to the `completeSave` function located  on `onsubmit` attribute of form's HTML tag

ex: `<form onsubmint="completeSave(event)">`

since the `this` keyword doesn't evaluate to the form, you gotta select it manually

```
function completeSave(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var thisForm = $(event.target);
  console.log(thisForm.find('input[name="name"]').val())
}
```

and the `input[name="name"]` will be the one whos form is submited

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

For sure you should add unique id to your forms

```
<form class="form" role="form" id="form1" onsubmit="completeSave(form1)">
 <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>نام محتوا</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
               value="{{$media->name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" id="{{$media->id}}" class="btn blue">ارایه</button>
    </div>
</form>
<form class="form" role="form" id="form2" onsubmit="completeSave(form2)">
 <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>نام محتوا</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
               value="{{$media->name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" id="{{$media->id}}" class="btn blue">ارایه</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and your javascript code could look like this:

```
function completeSave(form) {
      event.preventDefault();      
      var input = $("#" + form + " :text");
      console.log(input.val());
}
```